# Finished with status: 'connection error'

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that seems to work fine, but for the first 15 seconds or so (after being triggered from a pubsub topic) seems to just bounce between restarting execution and finishing with `status: connection error`Usually around the fifth try the function works fine. Here is the section of my logs that I'm noticing the issue in:

```
 157979520007507 Function execution started functionName 157979520007507 
 157979520007507 Function execution took 2351 ms, finished with status: 'connection error' 
 157979520007507 Function execution started functionName 157979520007507 
 157979520007507 Function execution took 2284 ms, finished with status: 'connection error' 
 157979520007507 Function execution started functionName 157979520007507 
 157979520007507 Function execution took 2582 ms, finished with status: 'connection error' 
 157979520007507 Function execution started functionName 157979520007507 
 157979520007507 Function execution took 3286 ms, finished with status: 'connection error' 
 157979520007507 Function execution started functionName 157979520007507
```

and the next log entries indicate that the function is operating normally. I haven't found any documentation about what this error might mean, or what the connection is between (pubsub & my function?, function instances in different datacenters?)

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the [minimum code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: is there a document that describes all the finishing statuses? a 4 minute development cycle is a while to try to pare my code line by line.

Comment: Pubsub is probably resending the payload because the function has an error. See this article for more info https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Functions: Unclear "connection error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598089/firebase-functions-unclear-connection-error)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same message and got it fixed by updating firebase-tools:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Hopefully, this works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

A Firebase Cloud Function was returning on every other execution:

**Function execution took 7 ms, finished with status: 'connection error'**

Re-installing firebase tools with:  `sudo npm install -g firebase-tools`

and then re-deploying the function solved the problem.