# Firebase realtime database triggers: When async and when not

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

In the documentation on Firebase triggers, we do not see the `async` word:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#reading_the_previous_value
Let's say I have two versions of a function, one is with `async`, and one without, like so:

```
exports.recountTotalCaloriesOnUpdate2 = functions.database.ref('/mealsOf/{userId}/{day}/meals')
    .onUpdate(
        (change,context) => {
            let uid= context.params.userId;
            let day= context.params.day;
            if ( !change.after.exists() ) return null ;
            if ( !change.before.exists() ) return null ;
            const collectionRef = change.after.ref;
            let finalSum = collectionRef.ref.once('value').then((snap) => {
                let sum = 0;
                snap.forEach((child) => {
                    //console.log(child.val().numCalories);
                    sum = sum + parseInt(child.val().numCalories);
                });
                return sum;
            });
            /*
            return await counterRef.ref.transaction((cnt) => {
                 return finalSum;
            });
            */
            return dbroot.ref(`mealsOf/${uid}/${day}/totalCalories`).set(finalSum);
            /*
            return await dbroot.ref(`mealsOf/${uid}/${day}/totalCalories`).set(finalSum).then( (a) => {
                return null ;
            }).catch( (error) => {
                return null ;
            });
            */
        }
    );
```

and with `async`:

```
exports.recountTotalCaloriesOnUpdate2 = functions.database.ref('/mealsOf/{userId}/{day}/meals')
    .onUpdate(
        async(change,context) => {
            let uid= context.params.userId;
            let day= context.params.day;
            if ( !change.after.exists() ) return null ;
            if ( !change.before.exists() ) return null ;
            const collectionRef = change.after.ref;
            let finalSum = await collectionRef.ref.once('value').then((snap) => {
                let sum = 0;
                snap.forEach((child) => {
                    //console.log(child.val().numCalories);
                    sum = sum + parseInt(child.val().numCalories);
                });
                return sum;
            });
            /*
            return await counterRef.ref.transaction((cnt) => {
                 return finalSum;
            });
            */
            //return dbroot.ref(`mealsOf/${uid}/${day}/totalCalories`).set(finalSum);
            return await dbroot.ref(`mealsOf/${uid}/${day}/totalCalories`).set(finalSum).then( (a) => {
                return null ;
            }).catch( (error) => {
                return null ;
            });
        }
    );
```

What is the difference? Does it make a difference to Firebase?
Also, in calculating `finalSum`, my `let finalSum = await ...` am I making sure this `finalSum` is available in the subsequent lines, i.e. does the thread of execution `.join()` the calculation, in Java's parlance?
But the real problem with this code is that

```
return await dbroot.ref(`mealsOf/${uid}/${day}/totalCalories`).set(finalSum).then( (a) => {
                return null ;
            }).catch( (error) => {
                return null ;
            });
```

always gives me message:
[image]
for the case *without* `async`,
and [image] 
for the case *with* `async`.

What I have is a path `mealsOf/{userId}/{day}/meals/{mealId}`, and I push a new meal there. So I put this trigger to update the counter at `mealsOf/{userId}/{day}/totalCalories` whenever a write/update happens at the path `mealsOf/{userId}/{day}/meals`. How to deal with the above exceptions?

EDIT: You can read about `async/await` elsewhere, e.g. https://hackernoon.com/understanding-async-await-in-javascript-1d81bb079b2c (just a random link, lost of material out there!)
As to my particular case, I let the `async` be there, heeded to the actual error message, and replace the last line with this:

```
return dbroot.ref(`mealsOf/${uid}/${day}/totalCalories`).set(""+finalSum, (error) => {
                if ( error )
                    console.log(error.message);
            });
```

and finally got my tests pass with clean execution. So, `NaN` tells us it is safest to convert everything into string.

EDIT: Look [Firebase Functions: Unclear "connection error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598089/firebase-functions-unclear-connection-error) to see that even the last line I've pasted has to have `await` keyword. Otherwise, sometimes you can get an error `connection error`because of unresolved promises.

Comment: The async keyword on a function just tells JavaScript that you are intending to return a promise from that function that resolves when all the pending work in that function is complete.  Learn more about how to correctly deal with promises in Cloud Functions using my video tutorial series.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/