# Random Error: could not handle the request in cloud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I have this code:

```
const checkNick = express();
checkNick.use(cors({origin: true}));
checkNick.get('/:nick', cors(), async (req, res, next) => {
    const nick = req.params.nick;
    const tmp = await admin.database().ref(C.Users).orderByChild('nickname').equalTo(nick).once('value').then(r => r.val()).catch(e => console.log(e));
    console.log(tmp, typeof tmp);
    if (tmp === null) {
        res.json({'exists': false});
    } else {
        res.json({'exists': true});
    }
});

exports.checkNick = functions.https.onRequest(checkNick);
```

And the problem is this:

Sometimes when I make the call I get this in the response:

```
{"exists":true}
```

which is what I want, but doing another call, I get this:

```
Error: could not handle the request
```

And in the `google functions console` log i get

```
Connection Error
```

The address is the same.

```
https://my.address/checkNick/nick
```

And when making the call it sometimes works, and once every 10 or 20 tries it errors out. Why is that?

Edit. If you're flagging please comment what's wrong with this question. My code acts weird, so I'm asking why this could be. Is there any other info can I provide?

Comment: Connection errors are things that just happen.

Comment: So there is nothing I can do to prevent them?

Comment: weird. check this question, maybe it will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598089/firebase-functions-unclear-connection-error